# How to constraint a foreign key to a subset

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `employee`, and each of them can fulfill different roles, like `inspector` and `constructor`. I also have another table with a column where I can store what inspector is on the job.

People can play different roles, but roles don't have to be added dynamic; a column for every role on the employee would be sufficient. This would also be handy, because we are resources-constrained at the moment, and our users use Postico for maintaining data (for the moment), so a simple data-model is preferable. With a foreign key we can use the 1:N selector of Postico.

I tried to create a foreign key constraint to a (materialized) view, but that's not supported by Postgresql. Also the following foreign key is not allowed:

```
FOREIGN KEY("inspector_id", TRUE) REFERENCES employee("id", "is_inspector")
```

Do I have any option, other than duplicating data in multiple tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you don't have to duplicate data.

If you add an `inspector` table, that's not duplicating. You need an "inspectors" entity in your model, you add an "inspector" table. Only the `inspector_id` values will be duplicated which is fine. So, that's solution A.

Solution B might be to add a an `is_inspector` column in the table you want to have the foreign key and restrict that column to `TRUE`:

```
is_inspector BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
CHECK (is_inspector),
FOREIGN KEY (inspector_id, is_inspector) 
  REFERENCES employee (id, is_inspector)
```

I would go for solution A every time but if solution B simplifies your application code for some reason, it still solves the issue and enforces the same requirements. But if you later need other tables to reference "inspectors", you'll need a boolean column in every one of them as well. So, solution A is the more simple approach as it would not require any such boolean columns at all (not even at the `employee` table, you can find the inspectors by joining to the `inspector` table).

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, solution A is to add a table for every role with one column which is both primary key and foreign key to the employee table. The disadvantage to this solution in my situation: in Postico you only see a list of numbers in the 1:N selector... Solution B seems OK for now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly. .

Comment: I'd set the `DEFAULT` to false - surely only a minority of employees are inspectors. I'm giving a +1 to this question (and answer) because it raises an interesting point: why can't there be `PARTIAL FOREIGN KEY`s?

Comment: Solution B also needs a unique constraint on the composite foreign key.

Comment: @doekman you are absolutely right. I'll edit and correct.